# Find the Maximum number in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

[image]

How do I find the **most popular book among all customers** from the table above? (cid = 'customer id')?

I have

> select Title, sum(c.quantity) from cart c group by c.ISBN;

which gives me the following results

> `+-----------------------------------------+-----------------+
>       | Title                                   | sum(c.quantity) |
>       +-----------------------------------------+-----------------+
>       | Writing Skills                          |               5 |
>       | Fundamentals of Database Systems        |               2 |
>       | Database Management Systems             |               5 |
>       | Data Mining, Practical Machine Learning |               4 |
>       +-----------------------------------------+-----------------+`

I know the Max() function in mysql can achieve my goal, but I do not know to implement Max() and Sum() together.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get most popular book/books you can use following query

```
select c.ISBN,c.Title, sum(c.quantity) soldQuantity
from cart c 
group by c.ISBN,c.Title
having soldQuantity = (
    select sum(quantity)
    from cart  
    group by ISBN,Title
    order by sum(quantity) desc 
    limit 1
)
```

Note there can be more than 1 books which share same highest quantity

Answer (score 2):

The following SQL statement should give you the book with the most quantity

```
SELECT
    Title, 
    sum(c.quantity) AS total_count
FROM 
    cart c 
GROUP BY 
    c.ISBN 
ORDER BY 
    total_count DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Note: You really should put the books in a seperate table titled "books" with two columns, "id" and "title". You can then change the "title" column in your original table to "book_id" and make it a foreign key to books.id. This will greatly improve the speed of your SQL calls.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Hi one approach would be using sub queries like this:

```
SELECT TITLE, MAX (SUMMATION)
FROM (SELECT TITLE, SUM (C.QUANTITY) SUMMATION
      FROM CART C
      GROUP BY TITLE, C.ISBN) LIST
GROUP BY TITLE, SUMMATION
```